# ¿Error "undefined is not an object" en plugin react-native iOS para MercadoPago?

Tags: ios, mercadopago, react-native

El problema es que necesito llamar a *Mercado Pago* desde mi aplicación que está hecha en react-native, pero no encuentro la forma.

Encontré una, pero es solo para *Android*.

¿Cómo puedo integrarlo, existe algún SDK o Plugin Oficial de MercadoPago?

Para poder dar mas información y poder hacer mas pequeño el ámbito de la respuesta, intente usar el reac-native-mercadopago que me recomendaron 
https://github.com/shovelapps/react-native-mercadopago
pero al momento de llamar a la funcion startCheckOut

```
RNMercadopago.startCheckout(publicKey, prefId, null, false, (payment) => { this._success(payment)}, (error) => { this._failure(error) });
```

sobre una llamada de un boton, estoy obteniendo el siguiente mensaje

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNMercadopago.startCheckout)
```

de esta manera estoy llamando la referencia:

```
import RNMercadopago from 'react-native-mercadopago';
```

todo estoy lo estoy haciendo en el archivo index.ios.js
saludos

Comment: Esto debería ser algo cercano a lo que buscas https://github.com/shovelapps/react-native-mercadopago